# cannot invoke 'append' with an argument list of type '(T)'

Tags: arrays, swift, generics

Just got this strange error when trying to write a stack with generic type in latest playground.
I really don't understand what's wrong here, can someone explain to me why I got this error?

```
class MyStack<T> {
    var stack1 = [T]()

    func push<T>(value: T) {
        stack1.append(value)  // Error: cannot invoke 'append' with an argument list of type '(T)'
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The class is already generic, no need to make push generic too

```
class MyStack<T> {
    var stack1 = [T]()

    func push(value: T) {
        stack1.append(value)
    }
}
```

When `push` is declared as `push<T>`, the generic parameter overrides the one defined on the class. So, if we were to rename the generic parameters, we'd get

```
class MyStack<T1> {
    var stack1 = [T1]()

    func push<T2>(value: T2) {
        stack1.append(value)  // Error: cannot invoke 'append' with an argument list of type '(T2)'
    }
}
```

presented like this, it makes sense that we cannot push a `T2` in `[T1]`.

Comment: Thanks a lot! It really helpful.